# String value in Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to use obj to store string values, inside of the string, there is a comma, but this is not working in the project.

```
const resizedUrl ={
    'mobile': "'images','400x/images'",
    'tablet': "'images','700x/images'",
    'desktop': "'images','1000x/images'",
};

function imageUrlResizer(para) {

    console.log(11111, resizedUrl.tablet);

    if(!!isMobile()) {
        para = para.replace(resizedUrl.mobile);
    } else if(!!isTablet()) {
        para = para.replace(resizedUrl.tablet);
    } else {
        para = para.replace(resizedUrl.desktop);
    }
    return para;
}
```

I want to use `'images', '700x/images'` inside the `replace`. But when it is running, the value becomes `'\'images\', \'700x/images\'` . I have tried this code inside codesandbox, it works fine.

This code is running in the backend, with node.js

Could anyone helps?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry, just deleted

Comment: when you say you have tried this code inside codesandbox, can you share the code you used there?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want a quick fix this will work:

```
const resizedUrl ={
    'mobile': ['images','400x/images'],
    'tablet': ['images','700x/images'],
    'desktop': ['images','1000x/images'],
};

function imageUrlResizer(para) {
    if(!!isMobile()) {
        para = para.replace.apply(para, resizedUrl.mobile);
    } else if(!!isTablet()) {
        para = para.replace.apply(para, resizedUrl.tablet);
    } else {
        para = para.replace.apply(para, resizedUrl.desktop);
    }
    return para;
}
```

the `replace` method expects 2 arguments, your code was only providing one.

for information on how `apply` works, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

A better approach would be to restructure your `resizedUrl` object so it's usage and purpose are straightforward.